# Vectorized implementation of np array difference

Tags: numpy, vectorization

Let's assume I have two arrays: x = [1,2,3] and y = [ 0,1,2].  x and y arrays always have the same length. What  I want to do is x - y_i for i in len(y). The vanilla implementation of the above calculation is as follows:

```
diff = np.zeros((x.shape[0]))
for i in range(y.shape[0]):
  diff[i] = np.sum(x - y[i])
```

My question is about vectorized implementation of the above code. Is there any way to implement the above calculation without using a loop?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution, using [`numpy broadcasting`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
np.sum(x - y[:, None], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
array([6, 3, 0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another, using [`np.subtract.outer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html):

```
out = np.subtract.outer(x, y).sum(axis=0)
```

out:

```
array([6, 3, 0])
```